# Search API for ElasticSearch not returning all the logs

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, kibana, nest

I am wanting to get all the logs from elasticsearch from a asp.net core web api application using NEST. I created a controller named `ESController` to get the logs that are in elasticsearch. However, when I do so, on swagger it only displays the first log and not the entire list of logs. I even wrote to the console to see if I can view those logs there as well but it does not display. I do not have a model class for the logs. **Is there something wrong I am doing to retrieve/extract the logs from elasticsearch in the .net application?**

Console displays: "Valid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /elastic-search-app-logs%2A/_search?typed_keys=true"

[image]

swagger:

[image]

**Correct me if I am wrong, but in the ElasticSearch CLI running the command below will display the logs from elasticsearch:**

```
GET elastic-search-app-logs*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**So what I am trying to do is translate this code into .net with NEST.**

[image]

**The logs I am wanting to read/extract from elasticsearch into a .net application**
[image]

Any pointers/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_search` API is limited in the number of results it will return, even with a `match_all` filter.

The traditional way to get **all** results from Elasticsearch is [scroll search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results). More recently the recommended approach is to use `search_after` instead (see the scroll search link for more info).

Docs for the NEST client cover both [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/search-after-usage.html) and [scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scrolling-documents.html).

The `_search` API is limited to 10,000 results by default. While it's not recommended, you can change the limit with the `index.max_result_window` [index setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-max-result-window).

[edit: typo fix]

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this!